# Expectation of F. Normal Distribution.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

$\Gamma$ is $N(0,1)$ and $|\Gamma|$ is Folded Normal.

Show for $|\Gamma|\ge t$ (otherwise $0$) that the expectation $E(|\Gamma|)$ is twice the density of the normal dist.

So far: I have worked out up until the integral in which I get stuck at:

$\int_t^{\infty}z(e^\frac{-(z-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}+e^\frac{-(z+\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}dz)$

This integral doesn't seem correct as it doesn't simplify nicely (ignoring the coefficients for now.)

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried ? Writing the definition of $E(|\Gamma|)$ and using the symmetry of $N(0,1)$ should do the trick...

Comment: I was just editting that in. Updated

Comment: You can make a case decision.  
$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}  e^{-\frac 12 x^2} \ \ \text{if} \ x\geq 0  \\  -\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}  e^{-\frac 12 x^2} \ \ \text{if} \ x<0 \end{cases}$ Now calculate the expectation. Also note that $\int_0^{\infty} f(x)\, dx =-\int_{-\infty}^0 f(x) \, dx$

Comment: But doesn't this only give me that the expectation is double?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I got it. Simplifies well. I did have trouble finding when to introduce my condition $\ge t$.